# Applying conditional formatting formula to 1000 rows without changing row number

Tags: google-sheets

This might sound strange but I am trying to apply the custom formula in the conditional formatting rule to 1000 rows:

> =AND($A12="P0", (DATEDIF($D12, TODAY(), "d") >= $B$4))

Intuitively, one can drag and drop or copy format, etc and the row number changes automatically in the formula. But in the case of the custom formula in the conditional formatting rule, the row number does not change automatically ($A12, $D12).
Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to drag the format down. Create just one rule and put `A12:D` in the `Apply to range` box. See [Lance's explanation](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/60050658?msgid=60238341) of how absolute and relative addresses work in a conditional formatting custom formula rule.

Comment: =AND(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()="P0"), (DATEDIF(INDIRECT("D"&ROW()), TODAY(), "d") >= $B$4))
Used this formula but apparently AND and INDIRECT could not be used together in custom formatting.

Comment: The way you use `indirect()` in the formula is incorrect. Further, you do not need `indirect()` since you are referring to cells in the same tab. Try the recipe given in the answer. Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.